# Save text documents as .txt in Xcode

Tags: xcode, macos

sorry for the obvious question, I'm relatively new to coding. I'm making a simple text editor with the Document App template in Xcode (Mac), but it always saves as .exampletext. Is there a way to ask how you want to save the document? Thanks

I changed static var readableContentTypes: [UTType] { [.exampleText] } to  static var readableContentTypes: [UTType] { [.txt] }

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Do you want to save a file in Xcode or in your app?

Comment: Maybe this helps: [Developing a Document-Based App](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/documents_data_and_pasteboard/developing_a_document-based_app)

Answer (score 0):

When you create a document-based app project, Xcode includes an imported type identifier for the document. To change the file extension for the document, go to the imported type identifier and change the extension in the Extensions text field.

[image]

You can access the project editor that is shown in the screenshot by selecting the project file on the left side of Xcode's project window.

The following article provides more detailed information on document types:

[Document Types in SwiftUI Apps](https://www.swiftdevjournal.com/document-types-in-swiftui-apps/)